# "Use sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device" can be disabled on one Windows 10 computer but not another

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

My family has two computers that both currently have Windows 10 Home version 10.0.19042 Build 19042 installed. Neither of them have user profiles that are linked to Microsoft accounts (during setup, we ensured they weren't connected to the internet to avoid being forced to link them to Microsoft accounts).

Recently, one of these computers displayed the infamous "Let's finish setting up your device" screen ([example](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-10/why-am-i-getting-this-quot-let-s-finish-setting-up-your-device/m-p/1751604)) after installing a Windows update. To prevent this from happening again, I opened the *Sign-in options* screen (accessed by typing "sign-in options" at the Start menu, for reference), scrolled down to the *Privacy* section, and disabled "Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart".

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Toggle enabled]

I then went to do the same thing on the other Windows 10 computer, but the "Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart" toggle was disabled, preventing me from turning off this function:

[image: Toggle disabled]

Given that both of these computers are running the same version of Windows 10 Home, why is this toggle disabled on only one of them? How can I enable it so I can turn off the associated behaviour?

Comment: The most common reason for being unable to enable or disabled an option is that some other relevant option is disabled.  So what I would do is compare every setting and determine which option isn’t configured the same way.

Comment: One of the computers may have an attached device or driver for device that needs completing . Printers may do this and in that case the message is not from Microsoft and cannot be disabled.